# Embed PageViewController in ScrollView - Programmatically Swift 5

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, scrollview, uipageviewcontroller, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a PageViewController which shows 4 four view Controllers horizontally,

Can I embed all this viewControllers in a UIScrollView? It would be easier to manage some tasks.

Till now I tried doing this in PageViewController, conforming the PageViewController to UIScrollViewDelegate:

```
 for view in self.view.subviews {
            if let subView = view as? UIScrollView {
                subView.delegate = self
                subView.isScrollEnabled = true
                subView.bouncesZoom = false
        }
    }
```

But it actually recognises the scrolling for the single ViewController and not for the entire stack of four VCs. 
I'd like to have the contentSize of the ScrollView equal to the entire width of all viewControllers.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want a "horizontal page view controller" as part of a vertically scrolling scroll view? Or do you want the contents of 4 view controllers as subviews of a scroll view?

Comment: I would like to achieve the second option you said: but NOT "4 viewcontrollers as subviews of a scrollview" because it is actually what I'm doing with the upper code.
Instead I want to embed the ENTIRE content of ALL the viewcontrollers inside a single ScrollView so I can track the position of the scollable content and make swiping buttons up that track In which VC I'm currently In.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. In your comment you say *"NOT "4 viewcontrollers as subviews of a scrollview""* ... but you also say *"I want to embed the ENTIRE content of ALL the viewcontrollers inside a single ScrollView"*. Maybe if you try editing your question and describing what you want to do in **plain language**?

Comment: If I embed each View Controller in a scroll View when I print out the scrollView content Offset in ScrollViewDidScroll:  it restarts each time the ViewController scrolling phase is finished.
I want to have an scrollView which continuously tracks the movements through the ViewControllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot *change* a `UIPageViewController` into a scroll view. It already *is* a scroll view, but has a lot of built-in functionality for memory-managed paging through view controllers.

If your goal is to put 4 view controllers into a scroll view:

- create a new (plain) `UIViewController`
- add a `UIScrollView` and constrain it to all 4 sides
- add a `UIStackView` (Distribution: Fill Equally) to the scroll view
- constrain all 4 sides of the stack view to the scroll view's content layout guide
- constrain its height to the scroll view's frame layout guide height
- add 4 `UIContainerView`s to the stack view
- embed each of your 4 "page" view controllers into the 4 containers
- constrain the width of the first container to width of scroll view frame layout guide

You now have a full-view `UIScrollView` where you can scroll back and forth through your 4 "page" view controllers.